# Inequality involving square root exponents

Tags: inequality

Show that $$ 2^ {\frac {1} {\sqrt 2}} + 2^ {\frac {1} {\sqrt 3}} \gt 3.$$
I tried to use AM-GM inequality and Jensen's inequality, but I didn't get to any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac1{\sqrt2}>\frac{7}{10}$$

because

$$10^2=100>7^22=98.$$

Then

$$\color{green}{2^{1/\sqrt2}}>2^{7/10}\color{green}{>\frac85},$$

because

$$2^{7}5^{10}=1250000000>8^{10}=1073741824.$$

Also,

$$\frac1{\sqrt3}>\frac47$$

because

$$7^2=49>4^23=48$$
and

$$\color{green}{2^{1/\sqrt3}}>2^{4/7}\color{green}{>\frac75}$$ because

$$2^45^7=1250000>7^7=823543.$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=2^x$ is a convex function, hence it is enough to prove that:
$$ 1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\geq\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$$
holds, or that:
$$ \frac{\log 2}{2\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\log 2}{2\sqrt{3}}\geq \int_{2}^{3}\frac{dx}{x}$$
holds, or that:
$$ \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{x}\geq\int_{2}^{3}\frac{dx}{x}$$
holds, or that:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{x+1}\,dx \geq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{5}}{x+2}\,dx $$
holds. However, the last inequality is easy to prove, by just considering how $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{x+1}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{x+2}$ behave on $[0,1]$. They both are convex functions.

Comment: Can you give me a proof without using integrals?